# Using system("command") in Linux in multithreaded environment not working?

Tags: c, multithreading, system

I am using system cmd in multithreaded environment in c program but it is always returning -1 giving error **"No Child process"** and errorno 10

```
 void test()
 {
    int ret;
    system("df -h");
    printf("%s %d",strerror(errno), errorno);
 }


 void* foo(void* p){
  test();
  }
```

NOTE: This code is in multithreaded environmet and also SIGACTION, SIGQUIT are used.

Comment: could you please provide a minimal reproducible sample

Comment: Your error probably means your program used too much memory.

Comment: Perhaps `df` is not in the default path?  You might try replacing it with `/bin/df` (or whatever the absolute path is that get printed when you do a `which df` in the shell) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: The posted code does not show that `system` returned -1. Also, I guess `errorno` is a typo?